# Why am I not getting scroll-bars with MigLayout manager?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane, miglayout

I'm writing a desktop application.
The environment is following:

- Java SE 10
- Eclipse IDE
- Java Swing
- MigLayout

The source-code, the important parts.

```
    textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    textPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "[grow]"));
    textPane.setContentType("text/plain");
    textPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 255, 0), 1, true));
                            
    scrollPaneScratches = new JScrollPane(textPane);
    scrollPaneScratches.setAutoscrolls(true);
```

That's the JTextPane area where I add, at run-time, some components.

This is where I add the components in:

```
      for(int key : keys) {
        JLabel header = retrieveHeader(key, types, allScratches);
                                    
        textPane.add(header, "wrap, growy");
                                
        JTextPane txt = new JTextPane();
        txt.setText(allScratches.get(key).getScratches());
                
        textPane.add(txt, "wrap, growy");
     }
```

Now what the problem is, that the JTextPane, which displays the components added at run-time, is not scrollable.
That's, the vertical scroll-bar supposed to appear, though but it does not.

Here is the image:

[image]

I tried different layout managers, but the contents is still not scrollable.

Why do not I get the scroll-bars?
N.B., I did use the search engine on this, for about a day.

Best regards

Comment: Why are you using a JTextPane? A JTextPane is for text, not for adding components with a layout manager. This will NOT cause the text pane to calculate the preferred size as components are added. A scroll pane will only work if the preferred size is calcuated dynamically. You should be using a `JPanel` if you want to use a layout manager when you add components.

Comment: Well, that I did not know that the JTextPane accepts text only.

Comment: You actually can add components using the `insertComponent(....)` or `insertIcon(...)` methods, but this will insert the component like a piece of text. That is it will just flow the component along with the other text. In any case the `JPanel` is the proper component to use for something like this. You have full control with the layout managers and you can nest panels with different layout managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I resolved my issue by following the suggestions by @camickr,
provided under the comments section.

That's, the new components I add under JPanel, rather than on JTextPane.
In that case, the scroll-bars do appear as expected.

That is:

```
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.ipady = 20;
    constraints.ipadx = 0;
    constraints.weightx = 0.0;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    
    JLabel header = retrieveHeader(key, types, allScratches);
                                                                            
    textPanel.add(header, constraints);
```